# QT600 Under Atmel Studio 7

Tags: avr, atmel, ide, qtouch

Using the QT600 development kit under Studio 7 in order to develop a touch interface, I can not get the kit to show up when not in programmer mode.

I've managed to write the example HEX onto the ATtiny88 board but when going out of programmer mode the kit won't show up on Studio.

Has anyone used this kit successfully? What steps are required to get the demos up and running?

Any help will be appreciated, the documentation I've read is really outdated.

[image]

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You edited out the question, so there was no question.

Comment: The "question" I edited out was "Is there anyone around here that used…?", and that is not a question semantically, but a meaningless opening phrase in the syntactical shape of a question... (Your new "what steps are necessary" question, on the other hand, is a question!)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have added more specific questions. I assumed anyone reading the post would understand what I am asking.

Comment: As said, the "what steps are necessary" is the core question. I wouldn't say it's the most specific question in the universe, but it's still a valid question :)